# CollapsingToolbarLayout and ViewPager

Tags: android

I am using a ViewPager inside CollapsingToolbarLayout.
The problem is that when I swipe the ViewPager which is not fully  expanded, toolbar title moves in the place where it should be with fully expanded state (by default to the bottom left corner). 
Then after collapsing title completely disappears.

Here is how my layout looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button_remember_word">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/pager_gallery"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="240dp"/>


            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_word_description"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/tmp_lorem"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And here is how I am setting the toolbar title:

```
  Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
  setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
  mToolbar.setTitle("A title");
  // also tried this way
  CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbarLayout = 
      (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar);
      collapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle("Another title");
```

Adding a couple of screenshots:
1. Normal expanded state
[image]

2. Normal collapsed state
   [image]
3. If in this state I swipe the ViewPager
   [image]
4. Title disappears
   [image]

[image]

Any pice of advice is appreciated

Comment: Could you show pictures of toolbar states?

Comment: added screenshots

Answer (score 1):

use `app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"` for your viewPager

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/pager_gallery"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                android:layout_height="240dp"/>
```

Comment: unfortunately it didn't help

Comment: https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/scrolling-techniques-for-material-design--cms-24435
did you visit this link ? 
it may help you